# AWS - Load Balancer + apache2 / Issue with 302 redirect response

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache2, aws-application-load-balancer

I am a AWS beginner. I have set up EC2 (ubuntu) Apache2 web server (PHP/SYMFONY) and a load balancer.

Everything works perfectly, except for responses contains 302 redirection.

"Redirection" responses are not returned to the browser and the network indicates "pending" than timeout.

It seems that load balance blocks responses with code 302 returned to the browser. The timeout is triggered by the browser.

I don't get this behavior when connecting directly to the ec2. I get it only through the load balancer.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or could provide any guidance on how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you access the URL in your browser, with your browser's network panel, do you see the 302? What `Location` value is in the response? My suspicion is it's working fine, but that your redirect URL is malformed in some way.

Comment: thanks @ceejayoz you were right ! Location pointed to non-https and the security group blocked port 80. thank you very much for helping me !!!